# What should taphold or click-hold do by default?

Tags: web-applications, user-experience

**This question is not specific to language/framework/platform.**

I want to know (and confirm), what should happen (by default) if a user taps and holds (or clicks and hold).

***This is more about basic usability and user experience.***

What would a user expect to happen if the user taps(or click) and hold.

For some clarification I did read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For myself I would expect additional actions or a contextual menu.

This comment on the [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) sums it up perfectly, which is where you may find more relevant answers for this topic.

> The press-and-hold (or long press) gesture on a mobile devices mimic the secondary button press on a computer mouse.
>
> Source - https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/24465/44188